# PhpStorm/Symfony error log red color in terminal. Ubuntu

Tags: phpstorm, symfony, ubuntu-16.04

[image]
I've been struggling with this problem for months. As you can see on picture, the error log in phpStorm terminal - its hard to read. I've been trying to change it in settings but nothing works. A few of my friends have the same problem on Ubuntu. I find on internet the same issue with Windows, the solution was to change color in windows register. But I can find any solution for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

I had the same issue, and that setting should do the trick.

Comment: IMO the answer is not clarified enough - the problem fix consists in change the definition of the red color to more clear (for example FF0000) and optional the gray color (the font of the error message)

Comment: Had the same issue, BFBFBF for gray and 9E3C34 for red look good enough